# How do you post files from tornado to a flask endpoint?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, tornado

I have flask api and a tornado application consuming the api. I need to POST files from a form and pass the request to the api, which will handle file uploading.

The flask resource looks something like this:

```
class ImageResource(BaseResource):
    path = '/images'
    def post(self):
        for file in request.files.values():
            upload(file)
```

The tornado handler looks something like this:

```
class ImageHandler(BaseHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        status, result = yield self.async_api.post('/images', self.request.data)
        self.write_json(result)
```

Them problem is that `request.files` is empty in `ImageResource` when using this implementation. What is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the flask `ImageResource` is expecting a `multipart/form-data` request. If the input to the tornado `ImageHandler` is already in `multipart/form-data` format, you may just need to pass the correct `Content-Type` header. To pass copy the header directly from the incoming request, do `fetch(url, body=self.request.body, headers=self.get_header("content-type"))`.

Comment: Yes you are exactly right. When the right headers are set, the request.files will be filled.